# Change of the geometry type in the three.js

Tags: three.js

How to change the type of the geometry from .spherical to .SphereBufferGeometry in three.js

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajyvyB

```
        // sphere
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
        var spherical = new THREE.Spherical();
        for ( var i = 0, l = objects.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
            var phi = Math.acos( -1 + ( 2 * i ) / l );
            var theta = Math.sqrt( l * Math.PI ) * phi;
            var object = new THREE.Object3D();
            spherical.set(1000, phi, theta );
            object.position.setFromSpherical( spherical );
            vector.copy( object.position ).multiplyScalar( 2 );
            object.lookAt( vector );
            targets.sphere.push( object );
        }
```

Comment: Your codepen is using `CSS3DRenderer`, which does not support `BufferGeometry`. If you can use `WebGLRenderer`, [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_constructed_from_geometry.html) is similar to yours.